# Stick DIV to bottom of page for desktop and mobile

Tags: html, css

I have an image that i want at the bottom right of my page with no margins on either the right or bottom. The code i have right now works great on the desktop.

```
 <div id="test">
    <img src="rat.png">
 </div>

 #test{
   position:fixed;right:0;bottom:0;
 }
```

The desktop view of the page has no scroll as all the content fits on the page without needing to scroll down. However the page is responsive so viewing it on a mobile collapses some elements and there for you need to scroll to see all the page. On mobile the image is not fixed to the bottom of the page, it is fixed to the bottom of the screen so when scrolling down it follows, i want it stuck to the bottom of the page if you need to scroll down to view it or not.

Any help will be appreciated.

For example the page is: http://dynamowerk.de/PixDive/test/
but if you view it from here http://mobiletest.me/ you will see the problem

Comment: Have a read of this webpage, it is very helpful https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: Sorry but in your webpage #rat is position: absolute not fixed

Comment: I was told to change that below

Answer (score 0):

Change the position from fixed to absolute.

Fixed constrains an element to the browser window, whereas absolute will constrain the element to a containing element.

In your case it would be best to have the div as a direct child of `<body>`.

Comment: If i change it to absolute this happends, http://mobiletest.me/ enter the url: http://dynamowerk.de/PixDive/test/

Comment: Take the html, body { height: 100% } out of your CSS

Comment: Didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

According to CSS specification the element with `position: fixed` is positioned relative to the browser window (screen) whereas `position: absolute` is positioned relative to its first positioned (non-static) ancestor element.

So, in your case the code may looks like:

#### CSS

```
html,body
{
    height: 100%;
}
#test
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <!-- some other tags -->
    <div id="test">
        <img src="rat.png">
    </div>
</body>
</hmtl>
```

Comment: Absolute makes the image stick to the bottom of the screen on mobile, not to the bottom of the page